# ALAsset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation return null

Tags: ios, null, alassetslibrary, cllocation

Hi i am struggling to get the GPS Location from ALAsset meta data, Here is the code i am using to get the location but the response it returning is null.

```
CLLocation *location = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
```

value for location in log is `null`.

Any help will be thankfull.

Comment: Did you try by accessing the metadata of assetRepresentation..?

    NSDictionary *metadata = asset.defaultRepresentation.metadata;
    NSLog(@"Image Meta Data: %@",metadata);
    NSDictionary *gpsdata = [metadata objectForKey:@"{GPS}"];

Once check this gpsData, if it is returning anything.. If this returns nil, may be the photo has not the location info.

Comment: yeah i tried that too, but that include {GPS} value in metadata for some of the images and some of the image doesnot even have the field in the dictionary.

Comment: Then, the image doesn't have the location info, may be that was taken when location is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Location informations are only available if location services are enabled for the caller, that was taken when location is enabled.